# How to change mysql date to "Ago" in php

Tags: php, mysql

So, for my mysql database, I have following date format: `2016-01-21 23:15:00`.

For its output (php), I am trying to change its format to "ago".

I tried to implement this [method](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/time-ago-function/).

This is how I am getting the date value:

```
$d .= $row->date. ',';
```

I am little lost to how to convert this to "ago" format.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: the function mentioned via the link you gave has one argument that you pass to the function - namely `time` so convert your date to a timestamp value before passing into the `ago` function

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ago( $time ){
    /* as found on css-tricks */
}

$date='2016-01-21 23:15:00';
$timestamp=strtotime($date);
echo ago( $timestamp );
```

Answer (score 1):

For calculating the time passed from a time to time you should convert them to timestamp. Then when you subtract the older time from newer one you will get the time passed in seconds. You can see an example below;

```
<?PHP
    header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    $oldTimeStamp = strtotime("2016-01-21 23:15:00");
    $nowTimeStamp = time();

    echo $oldTimeStamp ."\n";
    echo $nowTimeStamp ."\n";
    echo ($nowTimeStamp - $oldTimeStamp)." seconds passed";
?>
```

If you try to make an example for your situation;

```
<?PHP
    $mysqlTime = strtotime($row->date);
    $nowTimeStamp = time();

    //We use abs because we do not know the $row->date is in future or not ?
    echo abs($nowTimeStamp - $mysqlTime)." seconds ".($nowTimeStamp < $mysqlTime ? " to time of record" : " passed")."...";
?>
```

You shuld calculate the result according to your format, I mean minute,second,day etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are not passing your variable to the function.
Paste the function somewhere in your **executed** code (you could autoload it as a *helper* file via composer, as an example).

```
$d .= ago($row->date). ',';
```

This way you should get what you neeed.

Anyway for this kind of implementations I always prefer things like [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) which has a method called `diffForHumans()` that does exactly what you're looking for.